# RollupJS plugins not resolving

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, eslint, rollupjs

I suspect my problem lies in the way my file tree is structured, but I don't have much control over that because I'm working in a WordPress theme.

There are several plugin options in my `rollup.config.js` which are not working. I have changed the order of the import statements, the plugin order, changing paths, but the outcome is the same although the config file itself seems to be processed.

I am running `> rollup -c` from `mytheme/assets/js` via a shell script. This is so we can have separate builds for each theme while sharing a common `node_modules`. If this is a dumb way to do it, please school me.

I am running into a couple of problems when linting.

1. `node_modules` is supposed to be ignored by default, but I am seeing lint errors for `node_modules\babel-polyfill\dist\polyfill.js` and `node_modules\debug\src\browser.js`. I have attempted to explicitly exclude `node_modules/**` and the filenames themselves in the `eslint()` entry in `rollup.config.js` but it makes no difference.

   ```
   path\to\node_modules\babel-polyfill\dist\polyfill.js
   3:568   error    'exports' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
   ...
   ```
2. The `replace` plugin isn't replacing the `ENV` constant in `main.es6.js`:

   ```
   5:6 error  'ENV' is not defined     no-undef
   ```

Here is my file tree:

```
.
├── .babelrc
├── .eslintrc
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── node_modules/
├── web/
    ├── wp-content/
        ├── themes/
            ├── mytheme
                ├── assets
                    ├── js
                        ├── rollup.config.js
                        ├── build/
                            ├── main.js (build file)
                        ├── src
                            ├── main.es6.js (input file)
```

This is my shell script, which runs whenever a `*.es6.js` file is modified.

```
#!/bin/sh

server="$1/web/wp-content"

target_paths="$server/lib $server/themes $server/plugins"
child_path="/*/assets/js/rollup.config.js"

js_dirs=$(/bin/find $target_paths -type f -path $child_path)

echo "paths: $target_paths"
echo "config_files: $js_dirs"

for js_dir in $js_dirs
    do
        # parent directory  (assets/js)
        js_dir=$(dirname "$js_dir")

        # location of main.es6.js (assets/js/src)
        src_dir="$js_dir/src"

        # output directory (assets/js/build)
        build_dir="$js_dir/build"

        echo ""
        # cd $js_dir && rollup -c
        cd $js_dir && NODE_ENV=production rollup -c
    done
```

Here are the first few lines of `main.es6.js`

```
'use strict';
import 'babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill';
import debug from 'debug';

if ( ENV !== 'production' ) {
  debug.enable( '*' );
  const log = debug( 'app:log' );
  log( 'Debug logging enabled.' );
} else {
  debug.disable();
}
```

Here is the content of my `rollup.config.js`

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import eslint from 'rollup-plugin-eslint';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

export default {
  entry: 'src/main.es6.js',
  format: 'iife',
  dest: 'build/main.js',
  sourceMap: 'inline',
  plugins: [
    resolve( {
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: true
    } ),
    commonjs(), // to play nice with require(), which is not ES6+
    eslint(),
    babel( {
      exclude: ['**/assets/js', 'node_modules/**']
    } ),
    replace( {
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      ENV: JSON.stringify( process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev' )
    } ),
    uglify()
    //(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && uglify())
  ],
  onwarn: function ( warning ) {

    if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) {
      return;
    }

    if ( warning.indexOf( "The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'" ) > -1 ) {
      return;
    }

    // console.warn everything else
    console.warn( warning.message );
  }
}
```

Here is my `.eslintrc`

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "jQuery": true,
    "$": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
    "indent": [ 1, 2 ],
    "quotes": [ 0, "single" ],
    "linebreak-style": [ 0, "windows" ],
    "semi": [ 0, "always" ]
  }
}
```

Here is my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "ie > 10"]
        },
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "external-helpers"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paths are resolved relative to the config file, so `node_modules` (when it appears in `exclude` options etc) means `web/wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/js/node_modules` — which of course isn't what you want.

You could explicitly resolve `node_modules` like so...

```js
eslint({
  exclude: [`${path.resolve('node_modules')}/**`]
})
```

...but an alternative would be to have a single rollup.config.js file in the root of the project, and run the builds like so:

```js
// rollup.config.js in project root
var themes = fs.readdirSync('web/wp-content/themes');

var configs = themes.map(theme => {
  return {
    entry: `web/wp-content/themes/${theme}/assets/js/src/main.es6.js`,
    format: 'iife',
    dest: 'web/wp-content/themes/${theme}/assets/js/build/main.js',
    // ...
  };
});

export default configs;
```

(Note that this requires Rollup 0.43, which allows a config file to export an array of configs.)

The `'ENV' is not defined` error is happening because the `replace` plugin comes after the `eslint` plugin. Swap those round, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Rich. I will have to look into whether a single rollup.config would work for us, it's intriguing and would save a lot of hoop-jumping, for sure. 

However, the `path.resolve()` suggestion returned an error: `Error: path is not defined`. Where does `path` come from, is this a NodeJS object? 

Likewise, swapping the `replace` and `eslint` plugins had no effect on the `ENV` error.

I should add, if it's not clear already, that I am a complete Node newb.

Comment: You'll need to add `import path from 'path'` at the top of your Rollup config. Hmm, not sure about the `ENV` thing. Difficult to diagnose from a distance without a [repro](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/88c5fc2ac6dc941b22e7996af05d70ff) I'm afraid

Comment: Importing `path` clears the error but `exclude: [`${path.resolve('node_modules')}/**`]` is still including the polyfill. I'm wondering if it's because it's explicitly imported by my `main.es6.js` and is not a dependency of some part of the build process. Also, I think the global `rollup.config` might work for us. I'm on vacation for the next two weeks so I will have to leave it here for now. Thank you for your help.